# CopyTo of filtered rows in GoogleSheets with Apps Script

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I am new in using Apps Script. I am trying to improve the workflow in my master document, but I am having some troubles.

In a Google Spreadsheet, I have a bunch of filtered data in Sheet "DATA". All the shown data should be copied to a another sheet right above the actual position of the cursor in this new sheet. In sheet "DATA" I am counting the number of visible rows which I use to define how many rows should be inserted and then copied. This is the script:

```
function myfunction() {
  var spreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  var value = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet().getRange('DATA!$B$1').getValue()
   spreadsheet.getActiveSheet().insertRowsBefore(spreadsheet.getActiveRange().getRow(), value);
   spreadsheet.getActiveRange().offset(0, 0, value, spreadsheet.getActiveRange().getNumColumns()).activate();
   spreadsheet.getRange('DATA!2:300').copyTo(spreadsheet.getActiveRange(), SpreadsheetApp.CopyPasteType.PASTE_NORMAL, false);
};
```

If the actual filter shows for example 3 rows, it inserts 3 empty rows perfectly fine, but then copies the values of 4 rows and therefore overwrites the data which I have in the 4th row. It seems to always copy the 1st row of the dataRange, although it is hidden by the filter.

If I include the first row in the filter, the copy works perfectly fine as it inserts 4 empty rows and the 4 copied rows.

Any idea what I am doing wrong?

Comment: Your question can be greatly improved if you add a table to the question. [Tables](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/a/161855/) are a better alternative than spreadsheets to show your data structure.  If you share spreadsheets, make sure to also add images of your sheet to avoid closure of your question, as questions here must be [self](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/260455/) [contained](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/149892). [Your email address can also be accessed by the public](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/394304/), when you share Google files.

Comment: Consider using names for the sheets instead of single characters as readers might confuse single-character names with columns. Perhaps something like Source and Destination.